# Mongodb ignores $exists: true

Tags: mongodb, conditional-statements, exists

Can somebody explain me why this Mongodb condition:

```
{"_type": {$exists: true}, 'type': {$exists: true}, "_type": {$ne: 'cadastre'}}
```

returns items which do not contain _type property?

Comment: You have `_type` **twice** as keys of the object. You can only use the key **once**. Should be, `{"_type": {$exists: true, $ne: 'cadastre} }, 'type': {$exists: true}}`

Comment: Yes that make sense. Thanks.

Comment: You can also `$and: [{ _type: { $exists: true } },{ _type: { $ne: 'cadastre' } }]`. But that's long and horrible, so the "implicit AND" is IMHO usually more readable.

Comment: You have a mistake in first condition after 'cadastre'. There should be only one }